# Bucle infinito al ingresar caracteres con espacio por teclado

Tags: c++, string, bucles, dev-c++

Estoy intentando escribir un programa que me permita registrar 4 proyectos en un struct.
Este struct tiene ciertos campos del cual uno es el nombre del proyecto.

[image: Codigo del struct]

El problema radica en que cuando intento escribir un nombre, y este es mas de una palabra (o sea, separadas por espacio), el programa entra en un bucle infinito y no queda mas remedio que reiniciar la ejecucion

[image: Codigo en donde introduzco el nombre]

Como pueden ver en la imagen, en la linea 43 asigno el nombre del proyecto por teclado, pero esto luego se convierte en un bucle infinito tras presionar enter.

[image: Programa imprimiendo en bucle]

Tambien dejare el codigo del programa por si es necesario. Quisiera entender que esta sucediendo para poder solucionarlo. ¡Gracias!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    struct {
        int numero;
        char nombre[50];
        float presupuesto;
        float porcentaje = 0;
        float gasto = 0;
        
    } proyecto[4];
    
    int numProyecto = 1;
    int ejecucion = 1;
    int ejecucionf;
    int ejecutando;
    int respuesta;
    int respuestaCase = 0;
    
    float nuevoPorcentaje;
    float totalGastos;
    
    while (ejecucion = 1) {
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "--------------REGISTRO DE PROYECTOS--------------" << endl;
        cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "1. Registrar proyectos." << endl;
        cout << "2. Actualizar porcentaje de avance." << endl;
        cout << "3. Registrar gasto de proyecto." << endl;
        cout << "4. Informe general." << endl;
        cout << "5. Salir del programa." << endl;
        cin >> respuesta;
        cin.clear();
        if (numProyecto >= 1 && numProyecto <= 4) {
            switch (respuesta) {
                case 1:
                    proyecto[numProyecto-1].numero = numProyecto;
                    cout << "Introduzca el nombre del proyecto" << endl;
                    cin >> proyecto[numProyecto-1].nombre;
                    cout << "Introduzca el presupuesto del proyecto" << endl;
                    cin >> proyecto[numProyecto-1].presupuesto;
                    numProyecto++;
                    cout << "***PROYECTO REGISTRADO CON EXITO";
                    break;

                case 2:
                    cout << "Introduzca el numero de proyecto a actualizar (1 a 4)" << endl;
                    cin >> respuestaCase;
                    cin.clear();
                    respuestaCase = respuestaCase - 1;
                    if (respuestaCase == 0 || respuestaCase == 1 || respuestaCase == 2 || respuestaCase == 3) {
                        if (proyecto[respuestaCase].porcentaje == 0) {
                            cout << "Introduzca el nuevo porcentaje de completado del proyecto " << proyecto[respuestaCase].nombre << endl;
                            cin >> proyecto[respuestaCase].porcentaje;
                            cout << "***AVANCE ACTUALIZADO CON EXITO" << endl;
                        } else {
                            cout << "Introduzca el porcentaje actualizado de su proyecto " << endl;
                            cin >> nuevoPorcentaje;
                            cout << "Nuevo porcentaje: " << nuevoPorcentaje << "%, Porcentaje anterior: " << proyecto[respuestaCase].porcentaje << "%" << endl;
                            if (nuevoPorcentaje <= proyecto[respuestaCase].porcentaje) {
                                cout << "***ERROR, EL NUEVO VALOR DEBE SER MAYOR AL ANTERIORMENTE INGRESADO" << endl;
                            } else {
                                proyecto[respuestaCase].porcentaje = nuevoPorcentaje;
                                cout << "***AVANCE ACTUALIZADO CON EXITO" << endl;                      
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        cout << "***ERROR, INTRODUZCA UN VALOR ENTRE 1 Y 4";            
                    } 
                    
                    break;

                case 3:
                    cout << "Introduzca el numero de proyecto a registrarle el gasto (1 a 4)" << endl;
                    cin >> respuestaCase;
                    respuestaCase = respuestaCase - 1;
                    if (respuestaCase == 0) {
                        cout << "Introduzca el gasto del proyecto " << proyecto[respuestaCase].nombre << endl;
                        cin >> proyecto[respuestaCase].gasto;
                        cout << "**GASTOS REGISTRADOS CON EXITO"<< endl;
                    } else if (respuestaCase == 1) {
                        cout << "Introduzca el gasto del proyecto " << proyecto[respuestaCase].nombre << endl;
                        cin >> proyecto[respuestaCase].gasto;
                        cout << "**GASTOS REGISTRADOS CON EXITO"<< endl;
                    } else if (respuestaCase == 2) {
                        cout << "Introduzca el gasto del proyecto " << proyecto[respuestaCase].nombre << endl;
                        cin >> proyecto[respuestaCase].gasto;
                        cout << "**GASTOS REGISTRADOS CON EXITO"<< endl;
                    } else if (respuestaCase == 3) {
                        cout << "Introduzca el gasto del proyecto " << proyecto[respuestaCase].nombre << endl;
                        cin >> proyecto[respuestaCase].gasto;
                        cout << "**GASTOS REGISTRADOS CON EXITO"<< endl;
                    }
                    
                    break;

                case 4:
                    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                    cout << "---------------INFORME DE PROYECTOS--------------" << endl;
                    cout << "-------------------------------------------------" << endl;
                    cout << "PROYECTOS INCLUIDOS:" << endl;
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < numProyecto; i++) {
                        cout << proyecto[i].nombre << endl;
                    }
                    
                    cout << "TOTAL DE PROYECTOS INCLUIDOS: " << numProyecto-1 << endl;
                    
                    cout << "TOTAL DE PROYECTOS EN EJECUCION: ";
                    for (int i = 0; i< numProyecto; i++) {
                        if (proyecto[i].porcentaje > 0) {
                            ejecutando++;
                        }
                    }
                    cout << ejecutando << endl;
                    
                    cout << "TOTAL GENERAL DE GASTOS: ";
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < numProyecto; i++) {
                        totalGastos += proyecto[i].gasto;
                    }
                    
                    cout << totalGastos << endl;
                    break;

                case 5:
                    ejecucionf = 0;
                    break;

                default:
                    cout << "El valor introducido es invalido";
            }
        }
        
        //Este es codigo para saber que estoy guardando
        cout << "El numero de proyecto es: " << proyecto[0].numero << endl;
        cout << "El nombre de proyecto: " << proyecto[0].nombre << endl;
        cout << "El presupuesto de proyecto es :" << proyecto[0].presupuesto << endl;
        cout << "El porcentaje de completado es:" << proyecto[0].porcentaje << endl;
        cout << "El gasto de proyecto es: " << proyecto[0].gasto << endl;
        
        if (ejecucionf == 0) {
            ejecucion = 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No lei todo el codigo. Pero por lo que describes parece que estas leyendo
unicamente con `std::cin`. `std::cin` lee hasta que encuentra un eespacio. Si
quieres leer texto con espacios tienes que usar `std::getline`.

Comment: "*esto luego se convierte en un bucle infinito tras presionar enter*" ¿A qué te refieres? ¿Se queda la aplicación ejecutando algo sin que responda a la interacción del usuario o el bucle de petición de datos no acaba nunca?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que "cin >>" solo lee variables hasta donde coloques algún espacio o enter, prueba a cambiar todos tus "cin >> variable" por lo siguiente:

```
cin.ignore();
cin.getline(variable, size);
```

Donde size es el tamaño máximo de lectura (puedes probar a poner sizeof(variable) en caso de ser un char[] para no tener que especificar el tamaño). Aquí te coloco un ejemplo para el nombre, simplemente pon esto:

```
cin.ignore();
cin.getline(proyecto[numProyecto - 1].nombre, sizeof(proyecto[numProyecto - 1].nombre));
```